# Dawid Skene model for BUGS

Tags: bugs, stan

I'm a beginner in BUGS. I'm trying to code the Dawid Skene model in BUGS. The model is as follows:
[image]

Currently, I'm adapting the code from Stan, [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/stan-dev/w3IkGXLqs6k).

Here is the code:

```
model { 
   for (i in 1:I) {
     z[i] ~ dcat(pi[])
   }
   for (n in 1:M) {
     y[n] ~ dcat(theta[jj[n],z[ii[n]]])
   }
}
```

The data are

```
list(I=4, M=12, ii=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4), jj=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),y=c(1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1))
```

I cannot compile the code since I keep getting the error: "variable pi is not declared in model or data". Do you have any idea how I can model the Dawid Skene model in BUGS?

Edit: the context of this model is as follows: there are J annotators who need to label N items into K categories. There are M annotations ($M=N \times J$). The label of annotator $i$ for item $j$ is denoted as $r_{i,j}$. I need to find the actual correct label of each item $z_i$ and the competency of each annotator $\Theta$.

Edit 2: $\Theta$ is a $J \times K \times K$ matrix where each element in the matrix is in $[0,1]$. In addition, if $i,j$ are fixed, $\sum_{k=1:K}\Theta[i,j,k] = 1$. $\rho$ is an array of $K$ elements. Each element in the array is in $[0,1]$ and the sum of the elements is 1.

Edit 3: $r[i,j]$ is a categorical distribution taking $\Theta[i,j,:]$ as its parameter and returns an integer in $[1,K]$. $z[i]$ is also a categorical distribution which takes $\rho$ as a parameter and returns an integer in $[1,K]$.

The question is that I don't know how to model $\Theta$ in BUGS. Since it is also a parameter that I want to infer, I suppose I need to model $\Theta$ as a matrix in the model (which I don't know how).

Comment: Is $\pi$ a parameter? If so, you should declare it in the parameters block. Otherwise, you'll need to specify it as data... But I'm not sure where $\pi$ comes from in the STAN code, because none of your STAN code appears to correspond to the parameters in your diagram.

Comment: $\pi$ is actually $\rho$ in the diagram. Since I'm a beginner in BUGS, how do I know where $\rho$ is a parameter or not ? Thanks.

Comment: Parameters are estimated from the data. Are you estimating $\pi$? Surely this can't be all of your code, because your stan program never reads in the data...

Comment: I see. I'm estimating A, z and $\pi$. How about the initial values ? Should I initialize any ?

Comment: Is this a typical way to represent such a model? I've never seen it and I don't understand it.

Comment: this appears to be a relative of graph algebra notation, but... It does seem more opaque than is necessary...

Comment: The model is extracted from this paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.4606

Comment: stan will randomly initialize values by default, so that's not the most important consideration at this stage. What is important is that you correctly declare and read in your data and parameters. Since you haven't done that, it's impossible to critique your code.

Comment: I have just added the context of the model. Does it clarify anything ?

Comment: You still haven't declared data or parameters, so it's impossible to say if your model is correctly specified. What is `M`? What kind of parameters are $\Theta$ and $\pi$? Do they have bounds? What are their dimensions? The stan manual is really, really useful for learning about how the properly build  a model in stan. But do you want your answer to be about stan or about BUGS?

Comment: If it's true that $M=J\times N$, you'll have to declare $N$ and $J$. Or $M$.

Comment: Your model drawing omits the information about the distributions that accompanies the original.

Comment: @PatrickCoulombe I believe the drawing is a particular case of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_model) kind of model specification, but some details are missing.

Comment: I'm sorry for the ambiguity in the question. I have updated the question. I hope it makes more sense now.